# I want to create A Shortcode which displays the carousel I created

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have been trying to add the carousel as a shortcode but whenever I try it will end up crashing or not displaying this is being done in functions php and it appends to the body as of now please see the code below

```
    function flexslider_js() {
     
    $images = get_field('gallery');
    if( $images ): ?>
        <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                    <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['thumbnail']); ?>" alt="Thumbnail of <?php echo esc_url($image['alt']); ?>" />
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endif; 
    ?>
               <script>
                // Can also be used with $(document).ready()
                $(window).load(function () {
                    $(".flexslider").flexslider({
                        animation: "slide",
                        animationLoop: false,
                        itemWidth: 210,
                        itemMargin: 5
                    });
                });
                </script>                      
    <?php
    }
add_action('wp_head', 'flexslider_js');
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at adding a shortcode?

Comment: `add_action('wp_head'` - this will cause the output to land in the `head` element - clearly your carousel's HTML code does not belong in there.

Comment: Have you read through the [shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) documentation?

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the help I have found the answer this may not be the most efficient way of doing so if there any suggestions of a better way please be sure to say

```
function flexslider_js() {

?>
           <script>
            // Can also be used with $(document).ready()
            $(window).load(function () {
                $(".flexslider").flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    animationLoop: false,
                    itemWidth: 210,
                    itemMargin: 20
                });
            });
            </script>
            
            

<?php

$images = get_field('gallery');
$html = '';

foreach( $images as $image ) {
               $slides .= '<li><div class="slide-contents"><a href="' . $image['sizes']['medium'] . '" data-lightbox="carousel"><img src="' . $image['sizes']['thumbnail'] . '" class="slide-image"/></a></div></li>';
}

$html .= '<div id="carousel" class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">' . $slides . '</ul></div>';

console.log($html);
return $html;

}

add_shortcode( 'carousel', 'flexslider_js' );
```

Comment: That is pretty exactly how to do it! One mistake is that `console.log($html);` is JavaScript, not PHP, but I think I’d just a copy-paste problem